# How to test failed Paypal Payments via Stripe's Express Checkout Element

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

We're implementing Paypal on our site via Stripe's Express Checkout Element. Everything works as expected, however, we're unable to simulate a failed payment. None of the docs, either on Stripe's side or on Paypal's side, on how to simulate a failed payment works.

[image: Paypal button]

Clicking on the Paypal button opens Paypal in an external window like below

[image: paypal window]

Does anyone know how to test a failed payment flow? Stripe have been completely unhelpful on this one unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There are various PayPal [card rejection triggers](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/sandbox/card-testing/#link-rejectiontriggers), in particular `CCREJECT-REFUSED`. This trigger can be part of the name or address line 1. A card address can be edited in a [sandbox payer account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2Faccounts&intent=developer), via the account's https://www.sandbox.paypal.com interface.

Comment: There might be a configuration issue, as both of you have suggested using `CCREJECT-`. We've been using those but that's been unsuccessful

Comment: No configuration is required. But the triggers are for the billing address / name on card, not the shipping address.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm doing that but it is still a successful payment

Answer (score 1):

Card declines are surfaced to you through `error` in the `confirmPayment` result, as shown in the example snippet in the docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/elements/express-checkout-element/accept-a-payment#submit-the-payment

```
  const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    // `elements` instance used to create the Express Checkout Element
    elements,
    // `clientSecret` from the created PaymentIntent
    clientSecret,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: 'https://example.com/order/123/complete',
    },
  });

  if (error) {
    // This point is only reached if there's an immediate error when
    // confirming the payment. Show the error to your customer (for example, payment details incomplete)
    handleError(error);
  } else {
    // The payment UI automatically closes with a success animation.
    // Your customer is redirected to your `return_url`.
  }
```

For example, using the insufficient funds trigger `CCREJECT-IF`, my test integration receives this `error` to handle:

```
{
    "type": "card_error",
    "code": "payment_method_provider_decline",
    "decline_code": "paypal_payment_declined",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/payment-method-provider-decline",
    "message": "The transaction has been declined by PayPal. Ask the user to use a different instrument to complete the payment, or switch to another payment method. For further information, please contact PayPal support and reference this Debug ID: 6123ec123456c. PayPal issue: INSTRUMENT_DECLINED.",
    "payment_intent": {...},
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_123?t=1700000000",
    "shouldRetry": false
}
```

Comment: There might be a configuration issue, as both of you have suggested using `CCREJECT-`. We've been using those but that's been unsuccessful

Comment: You'll need to be more specific then about exactly what you're doing and what you mean by "unsuccessful".  I'd suggest writing in to Stripe's support team with precise reproduction steps so that they can investigate for you. https://support.stripe.com/contact